# javascript: how do I pass safe strings to an array for client side display without messing it up / ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

platform: ASP.NET 3.5 / C#

My requirement is this:

I want to create a rather large array on the server side (in C#) and pass it to the browser via

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("gBank", js);
```

My array is a 2-dimension array, and I am constructing it right to pass it to the client. Simple cases work fine.

My problem is the content of the array - there are several strings, for e.g.

```
[[4, 'hello there', 'this is \n one'],[5,'again','there's another string']] etc.
```

These strings can have new lines, ',- and other such characters including < > etc. I did a replace '\n' with '\n' and that was fine, but other characters like ' mess up the array string in the client side.

How do I pass these strings 'safely' so that the array is not messed on the client side, and the content displays as-is?

---

I found this code on Rick Stahl's blog

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx

and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: If you have the ability to use .NET 4.0 (or above) then [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914(v=vs.100).aspx) is available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly escape your Javascript string literals when building the JSON.

You can use the [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) and call `Encoder.JavaScriptEncode`.

However, it would be better to use a proper JSON encoder, such as the [`JavaScriptSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: Some JSON encoders do not encode codepoints U+2028 and U+2029 which are newlines in JavaScript, but not in JSON.  If you use a JSON library and are going to embed the result in JavaScript, check that "\u2028\u2029" works in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - see my edit, that link gave a simple but workable solution

Comment: +1 **"Use a proper JSON encoder"** Then you can do more with the same.